# Cannot customize my tabbar from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, customization, tabbar

i want to make a custom tabbar for my apps, and i already try to put my code in the first viewcontroller and it works!.
but here's the problem, i want to declare and put my code in Appdelegate.m, but when i run it, it only shows me a black tabbar controller with no image.
for your info, i embeding my tabbar controller from storyboard.

here's the code

```
    UIImage *selectedImage0   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1hov.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage1   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2hov.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage2   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3hov.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage3   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img4hov.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage4   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img5hov.png"];



    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

    tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_menu.png"];


    [item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
    [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
    [item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
    [item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through following link,
1) http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

2)http://www.simplecode.me/2011/12/05/tab-based-ios-apps-uitabbarcontroller/

3)http://sugartin.info/2011/07/01/customizing-tab-bar/

4)http://code4app.net/ios/TabBar-with-Expands/5004e0206803fa546a000001

5)http://www.guerrillawebsitedesign.co.uk/wordpress/index.php/2010/09/30/how-to-create-a-custom-uitabbarcontroller-for-the-iphone-with-different-background-images-and-icons-part-1-2/

Answer (score 0):

That code looks fine for me. How do you add `UIViewController` to `UITabBarController` in appDelegate? Isn't it like this?

```
//appDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
//and synthesize those

//appDelegate.m
self.viewController = [[SomeViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.viewController, nil];
```

You can access `self.tabBarController` and `self.viewController` reside in appDelegate from everywhere by using `((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)`